# ExecuteScalar throws NullReferenceException when calling a stored proc that returns 1

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection, sqlcommand, executescalar

I've done some research before posting this question and I'm aware of the fact that when there's no data returned, ExecuteScalar will throw  a System.NullReferenceException. That is why I modified my stored proc to "return 1" so there's guaranteed a return value. However, I'm still getting the NULL reference exception.

So I tried to use the SqlCommand to query a table that has data:

```
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ATableThatHasValues", conn)
```

When I ran execute scalar I was able to pick up a value so I know I have permission to query the database. I'm suspecting that this is some specific storeed proc permission setting that I missed?

I'd really appreciate any comment/suggestions as I've been stuck on this for a day now. :(

My code looks like this:

```
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("GetSomeValue", sqlConnection))
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", this.ID));
                //sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@State", 1 /* active */));

                byte retValue = (byte)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                return retValue;
            }
        }
```

THANKS!

Comment: Which line throws the exeception? Where is the stack trace?

Comment: You do understand the purpose of `ExecuteScalar`, right? It returns the first column of the first row of data, everything else is ignored. Is there a reason that you're using it along with `SELECT *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Random guess**

You are using RETURN so there is no dataset to read column 1, row 1 for ExecuteScalar

Use SELECT or OUTPUT parameters

Edit: Actually, not so random

`RETURN 1` is not a result set: it's a "special" parameter

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int)).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. My original stored proc actually returns a resultset but for debugging purposes I changed it thinking it would help me debug but it actually derailed me entirely. I was so frustrated that I missed a obvious small typo in my original stored proc that started the whole debugging process. :( Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to elaborate on what @gbn said. When you execute SQL code you can return information in three different ways, `OUTPUT` parameters, tabular data and/or a single `RETURN` value. Like @gbn said, `RETURN` values are essentially specialized `OUTPUT` parameters. `ExecuteScalar` only sees information from tabular data, namely the first column of the first row. If no tabular data is received when you call `ExecuteScalar` a null value is returned instead. If you try to do something with this null value then obviously you'll get a NRE.